# The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, struct, properties, abstract, extern

I need some help with a c# error.

Why this return me this error ?

> Error : The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item.

```
public struct NetworkViewID
{
        public static extern NetworkViewID unassigned
        {
            [WrapperlessIcall]
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            get;
        }
}
```

When i remove the 'extern' keyword i have this error returned:

Error: Must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. The auto-implemented properties must define the get and set accessors.

Thank you, if somebody have an idea to fix it please tell me.

Comment: The getter has no body if you don't mark it with abstract, so you'll have to provide one. eg: `get { return _foo; }` Another option is to give it a private setter, so that the compiler generates a field for you. Not sure what you're trying to do here though?

Comment: I tryed it and i have same errors.

Comment: Do you require the `WrapperlessIcall` and `MethodImpl` attributes? These basically state that the method is framework-internal and as such implemented in the framework itself. If they aren't, there's no body. Should work if you remove the attributes and add a private setter, as @Caramiriel suggested, but that may defeat what you tried to do in the first place ... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes i require WrapperlessIcall and MethodImpl.

Comment: Exemple i have the same error in the Matrix4x4 structure       `public extern bool isIdentity
        {
            [WrapperlessIcall]
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
            get;
        }`

Comment: when i remove attributes and i add a private setter i have the same error The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item.